# Creating Release build of dojo to a custom folder

Tags: dojo, release-builds

I need to create a **release build of Dojo**. I'm able to do that using the `profile` that I created. The release build is getting generated inside `release` folder of `Dojo` source. Is it possible to move that to a custom folder? Can you please let me know?
I'm trying to do this using my ANT script.

```
<java fork="true" dir="${shrinksafe.util.path}/buildscripts" classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main">
<arg value="build.js" />
<arg line="releaseDir={dojo.work.folder}/apac/html profile=test_dojo action=clean,release version=1.3.2test_v1.0 releaseName=test_dojo cssOptimize=comments copyTests=false cssImportIgnore=layout/SplitContainer.css" />
<classpath>
<pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/js.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar"/>
<pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
</classpath>
</java>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my example and works fine.

```
<java fork="true"
     failonerror="true"
     dir="../dojo/util/buildscripts"
     classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main">
    <classpath>
       <pathelement location="../dojo/util/shrinksafe/js.jar"/>
       <pathelement location="../dojo/util/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>
        <arg value="build.js"/>
        <arg value="version=1.6.0"/>
        <arg value="profileFile=${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resource/js/encuestame.profile.js"/>
        <arg value="action=clean,release"/>
        <arg value="releaseDir=${project.build.directory}/dojo-compiled"/>
        <arg value="optimize=shrinksafe"/>
        <arg value="layerOptimize=shrinksafe"/>
        <arg value="cssOptimize=comments"/>
        <arg value="mini=true"/>
</java>
```

Code inside pom file, line 276 [ANT Code inside pom.xml](https://github.com/encuestame/encuestame/blob/development/encuestame-war/pom.xml)

Comment: I tried this, it is not working for me. It creates a folder ${project.build.directory}

Comment: Please replace ${project.build.directory} with your own path .. I use this code inside of maven ..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `releaseDir=PATH_TO_THE_DIR` command line option when building.

Comment: I'm doing that. I'm using ANT to do this. This is how I do this.<arg line="releaseDir={work.folder}/dojo/release. But it the variable doesn't get resolved

Answer (score 0):

The releaseDir property should be a path relative to util/buildscripts directory. So it cannot accept parameters like    ${project.build.directory}. You need to give a relative path like ../../dojoBuild